# How to use synchronized the object in AsyncTask doInBackground()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I got the trouble with using synchronized the object in background thread. I've specified the problem in sample nutshell:

1. I write the simple class like that:

   ```
   public class UIThreadClass {

      MyObject object;

      UIThreadClass() {
         object = new MyObject();

         object.doActionOne();
         object.doActionTwo();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Now my task is improve the code by put two method to non-UI thread.
       I am using AsyncTask

   **For doActionOne()**

   ```
   private static class DoActionOneTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       private WeakReference<MyObject> wObject;

       DoActionOneTask(MyObject object) {
           wObject = new WeakReference<>(object);
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
          if(wObject.get() != null) {
             MyObject myObject = wObject.get();
             myObject.doActionOne();
          }

          return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   **For doActionTwo()**

   ```
   private static class DoActionTwoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       private WeakReference<MyObject> wObject;

       DoActionOneTask(MyObject object) {
           wObject = new WeakReference<>(object);
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
          if(wObject.get() != null) {
             MyObject myObject = wObject.get();
             myObject.doActionTwo();
          }

          return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   **Now call them in UI thread**

   ```
   public class UIThreadClass {

      MyObject object;

      UIThreadClass() {
         object = new MyObject();

         new DoActionOneTask(object).execute();
         new DoActionTwoTask(object).execute();
     }
   }
   ```

The question is:

> When using AsyncTask - how to synchronized the object to make sure
>   that the doActionTwo() alway call after doActionOne() method ?.

I have tried using **synchronized (myObject) {myObject.doActionOne();}** in doInBackground() but the system is warning me that myObject just local variable and it is difficult to guarantee correctness.

Can anyone help me this situation ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: AsyncTask as the name suggest it will perform the  task asynchronously, You can create a separate thread and perform operations and synchronise them

Comment: instead of synchronized use ThreadPoolExecutor that will run simultaneously. for more have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466464/5110595)

Comment: you can start your 2nd Asynctask from the first one's onPostExecute method or use ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: BTW the way you use WeakReference is not safe, you should store the `wObject.get()`in a variable and perform your if-statement. Calling `wObject.get()` again can potentially give a null reference at some point.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya: But what I want is "how to synchronized". The problem is solved, thanks

Comment: @HemantParmar: Yeah, I know about ThreadPoolExecutor, but my task is using both of them and compare between. The problem is solved, thanks.

Comment: @himel: thanks for you suggestion but not using onPostExecute here because of not using callback requirement. The problem is solved, thanks

Comment: @Enzokie: Can you explain why calling wObject.get() again can potentially give a null reference, pls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. They will execute serially as per the Android docs

```
Order of execution
When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.
```

Comment: Great, thanks you guy, you are right, that's my mistake not reading docs clearly.